# Dynamic form Object Angular reactive From

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Array. I need to send the form data as object along with form submit. check the below Code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9astq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Above stackBlitz doesn't really tell what you're expecting. Can you implement the form over there?

Answer (score 1):

you can use angular reactive forms and use form array for the same to implement dynamic form. I am adding the link for angular documentation :

Angular Reactive Forms - https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Form Array - https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Answer (score 0):

I have find out some solution with working solution. Go through the following solution.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2tmrqr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html